# Auto Packaging a PHP application

Tags: php, package, production

For the project I have been working on before releasing, I need to remove development files, rename the project folder and then zip the project up any time I update the version

Is there any software (perhaps a macro) that could do something like this on Windows?

Comment: Have you looked at phing? http://www.phing.info/trac/

Comment: +1 for phing. In combination with phing, you might also look into packaging it as a PEAR package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHING worked pretty nicely. (Needed to add an answer to this Q)